# Switching from native iOS gui to Qt gui

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, qt

I currently have a native iOS GUI and a Qt-GUI. I'm trying to switch from one to another.

To be clear: When i click on a button on the native GUI i want the Qt-GUI to show up and vice versa.

I already found out which libraries i have to add to be able to use the Qt-Stuff. I created a `QApplication` in the `AppDelegate.mm` file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *) launchOptions {
    // receive int argc, and char** argv for the QApplication.
    _qApp = new QApplication(_argc, _argv);
}
```

Furthermore my Qt application looks (at the moment) like this:

```
void createQtGUI() {
    QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton("Some Button");
    QLabel* lbl = new QLabel("QTGui");
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(lbl);
    layout->addWidget(btn);

    QWidget* window = new QWidget();
    window->setLayout(layout);
    window->show();
}
```

I'm calling the `createQtGUI` method in my `ViewController.mm` when pressing a button in the native iOS GUI. The code runs without throwing any error, but:

**The Qt-GUI is not shown. The application still shows the native gui without switching to the Qt-GUI.**

Has anybody got any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I very much doubt this will work as both frameworks provide a complete environment which are designed to have full control of the run-loop, event handling, etc. etc.

Comment: I would say you forgot to call a `QApplication::exec()` method to start Qt event loop.

Comment: @Tomas That was my first thought too, but it seems that QApplication hangs itself into the native event loop. Also i've found a guide from someone who managed to do this and he mentioned explicitly that you don't have to call the exec() method.

Comment: @trojanfoe I've found a guide where exactly this is done under Qt 5.3. I pretty much feel that i'm only missing a small part, something like taking the Qt gui elements to a native ios View or something

Comment: @ParkerHalo Than try to call a `QApplication::processEvents()` in your native event loop. Qt events just have to be processed.

Comment: @Tomas EDIT: just tried it and nothing happened... Still only showing the native GUI

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've finally found out what was missing:

The Qt-Objects provide a method called `winId()`. This method returns a `WId` which actually is (on iOS) an `UIView*`.

You have to add that `UIView*` as Subview to your main view.

---

In order to achieve that I changed my `createQtGUI` method as follows:

```
WId createQtGUI() {
    ... // nothing changed here (only at the end)
    window->show();

    return window->winId();
}
```

And In my `ViewController.mm` (where I call my method):

```
- (IBAction)ButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    UIView* newView = (__bridge UIView*)reinterpret_cast<void*>(createQtGUI());
    [self.view addSubview:newView];
}
```

Note: The double cast `(__bridge UIView*)reinterpret_cast<void*>(...)` is necessary because you can't just cast from `WId` to `UIView*` in Objective-C++.

Comment: You should definitely mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Hi Parker : I am having almost same requirement. I am new to QT but i am a iOS developer. I have a module created in QT and want to open this module in native iOS app on any button clicked. Is it possible ? i believes it something like you already have done.

Comment: Hi @charanjitsingh , Yes it is possible. The QT Objects (like views) have a method `winId()` which returns a `UIView*`. You can embed that `UIView*` into your native application. For more information see my answer above

Comment: Thanks for reply: Yes i can see the way to describe above but my concern is i don't know even how to start my work. I have created "createQtGUI" in mainWindow.cpp qt project and i have viewController.mm in native iOS app. My concern is how i will communicate between two different projects and what should be the linkage steps. please help.